# Remove white space from the block when the menu item breaks in two lines

Tags: css

Below is the logic for the simple menu. The issue is when the text breaks into two lines extra white space is added to the `<a>` element

`white-space: nowrap` can remove white space, but will prevent the text from breaking, when the viewport width is not wide enough to naturally fit the text in one line. It's also not desired to set fixed-width on each child.

```css
.menu {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.menuItem {
  list-style: none;
  padding-right: 50px;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.menuItem a {
  display: inline;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.menuItem span {
  width: 12px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class='menu'>
  <li class='menuItem'>
    <a target='_' href='https://www.google.com'>Two Words</a>
    <span></span>
  </li>
  <li class='menuItem'>
    <a target='_' href='https://www.google.com'>
Two Words</a>
    <span></span>
  </li>
  <li class='menuItem'>
    <a target='_' href='https://www.google.com'>
Two Words</a>
    <span></span>
  </li>
  <li class='menuItem'>
    <a target='_' href='https://www.google.com'>
Two Words</a>
    <span></span>
  </li>
  <li class='menuItem'>
    <a target='_' href='https://www.google.com'>Two Words</a>
    <span></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: .menuItem { flex-basis: 0; } Try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added `flex-basis:0` to `a` tags.  Hope this helps.

```css
.menu {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 700px;
}

.menuItem {
  list-style: none;
  padding-right: 50px;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.menuItem a {
  display: inline;
  background-color: #ccc;
  flex-basis: 0;
}

.menuItem span {
  width: 12px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: green;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class='menu'>
  <li class='menuItem'>
    <a target='_' href='https://www.google.com'>Two Words</a>
    <span></span>
  </li>
  <li class='menuItem'>
    <a target='_' href='https://www.google.com'>
Two Words</a>
    <span></span>
  </li>
  <li class='menuItem'>
    <a target='_' href='https://www.google.com'>
Two Words</a>
    <span></span>
  </li>
  <li class='menuItem'>
    <a target='_' href='https://www.google.com'>
Two Words</a>
    <span></span>
  </li>
  <li class='menuItem'>
    <a target='_' href='https://www.google.com'>Two Words</a>
    <span></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

add `width: min-content` to your `<a>` tag style, this will remove extra space!

Comment: this is a nice approach. But  afaik this has very limited support. See https://caniuse.com/#search=min-content